# In SDL do I need to free the surface if I re-render text?

Tags: c, text, sdl

if I use the following code...

```
message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "Lorem Ipsum", textColor );
```

Do I need to free **message** before I can do this

```
message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "Lorem Ipsum part 2", textColor );
```

i.e. does it give me a new surface (and so I have to clean up the old one) or does it just blit over the old one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should free `message` with `SDL_FreeSurface` when you're done with it. The returned SDL_Surface is allocated with `SDL_AllocSurface()` , and is not reused, so you'll leak if you don't free it in this case.